# PHP Comma Delimiter or Explode for Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, delimiter, explode

I have a drag and drop JS plugin that saves strings as the following:

```
["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]
```

I have found that I can use str_replace in an array to remove both brackets and " char. The issue that I now have is that I have a invalid argument for passing through the foreach loop as it cannot distinguish each individual word.

```
$bar = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
$new_str = str_replace(str_split('[]"'), '', $bar);

foreach($new_str as $arr){

    echo $arr;

}
```

So the data now outputted looks as follows (if I were to echo before the foreach loop):

```
кровать,бегемот,корм,валик,железосталь
```

Is there anyway in which I can use a comma as a delimeter to then pass this through the foreach, each word being it's own variable?

Is there an easier way to do this? Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: is that json? you should probably just `json_decode()` it.

Comment: `foreach(explode(',',$new_str) as $arr)` But, as above, the js is using a regular js array. If you show how you are passing this to php, there will be a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can use `explode`, but you should recognize that you're getting JSON, so you can simply do this:

```
$bar = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
$new_str = json_decode($bar);

foreach($new_str as $arr){

    echo $arr;

}
```

With no weird parsing of brackets, commas or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is explode(). Take a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Look at the following code:

```
$bar = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
$new_str = str_replace(str_split('[]"'), '', $bar);
$exploding = explode(",", $new_str);

foreach($exploding as $token){

    echo $token;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got a JSON string and want to convert it to an array. There are a few ways to do this. You could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
like this:

```
$bar = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
$new_str = str_replace(str_split('[]"'), '', $bar);
$new_str_array = explode($new_str);

foreach($new_str_array as $arr){

    echo $arr;

}
```

or you could use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
like this:

```
$bar = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
$new_str_array = json_decode($bar);

foreach($new_str_array as $arr){

    echo $arr;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $aa = '["кровать","бегемот","корм","валик","железосталь"]';
    $bb = json_decode($aa);
    foreach($bb as $b)
     echo $b."\n";
?>
```

and the results is,

```
кровать
бегемот
корм
валик
железосталь
```